# basic python but wierd problem in hadoop-stream text value changes in MapReduce

Tags: python, linux, hadoop, mapreduce

I am processing a 121983 rows txt file over hadoop. But I met some wierd problem in the mapReduce phase.

This is my mapper function:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import re
pattern = r'\b[a-zA-Z0-9]+\b'
numline=0
for line in sys.stdin:
    numline+=1
    line =line.strip()
    words=re.findall(pattern, line)
    for word in words:
        print ('%s\t%s' % (word,1))
print("%s\t%s" % ("num line",numline))
```

This is my reduce function:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
worddict={}
nrow=0
totalwords=0
for line in sys.stdin:
    line=line.strip()
    word,count=line.split('\t')
    if word=="num line":
        nrow=int(count)
        continue
    
    totalwords+=1
    if word not in worddict.keys():
        worddict[word]=1
    else:
        worddict[word]+=1
wd_sorted=sorted(worddict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1],reverse=True)
print("There are %s lines in the text."%nrow)
print("The 100 most frequently used words are:")
for wd,cnt in wd_sorted[:100]:
    print("%s\t%s"%(wd,cnt))    
print("There are %s words in the text."%totalwords)
print("There are %s unique words in the text."%len(wd_sorted))
```

**The question is, I've tested my mapper function works well and gives the right row number (121983) by using the code `cat shakespere.txt | python WDmapper.py`(WDmapper.py is my mapper function and shakespere.txt is the file i need to process) but when I process that and output that in reducer function, it becomes 60845.**  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhqzz.png)

I am pretty sure this aint some limit for some numeric data type. And I am also pretty sure that the loop in reducer function went thru completely 121983 loops because in the end, there are correct number of words(910915).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sb7gd.png)

It might be some special feature of mapReduce process, but I am a super novice so can someone help me with it?